# Water flow From Bottom to Top using Metal Kit iOS

Tags: ios, swift, metalkit

I am creating an application, in which water will flow from bottom to top. i did many changes using source from https://github.com/FlexMonkey/ParticleLab

Please find video on link below, this is look like Milk, but i am trying to make it as real Water Flow.
http://expirebox.com/download/6e3c11ca4fb969df976b51628d1d9c89.html

[image]

```
func resetParticles(edgesOnly: Bool = false, distribution: Distribution = Distribution.Gaussian)
{
    func rand() -> Float32
    {
        return Float(drand48() * -20.005)
    }

    func rand2() -> Float32
    {
        return Float(drand48() * 4)
    }

    let imageWidthDouble = Double(imageWidth/8)
    let imageHeightDouble = Double(Float(imageHeight)/1)
    let randomSource = GKRandomSource()
    let randomWidth: GKRandomDistribution
    let randomHeight: GKRandomDistribution

    switch distribution
    {
    case .Gaussian:
        randomWidth = GKGaussianDistribution(randomSource: randomSource, lowestValue: 0, highestValue: Int(imageWidthDouble))
        randomHeight = GKGaussianDistribution(randomSource: randomSource, lowestValue: 0, highestValue: Int(imageHeightDouble))

    case .Uniform:
        randomWidth = GKShuffledDistribution(randomSource: randomSource, lowestValue: 0, highestValue: Int(imageWidthDouble))
        randomHeight = GKShuffledDistribution(randomSource: randomSource, lowestValue: 0, highestValue: Int(imageHeightDouble))
    }

    for index in particlesParticleBufferPtr.startIndex ..< particlesParticleBufferPtr.endIndex
    {
        var positionAX = Float(randomWidth.nextInt())
        var positionAY = Float(randomHeight.nextInt())

        var positionBX = Float(randomWidth.nextInt())
        var positionBY = Float(randomHeight.nextInt())

        var positionCX = Float(randomWidth.nextInt())
        var positionCY = Float(randomHeight.nextInt())

        var positionDX = Float(randomWidth.nextInt())
        var positionDY = Float(randomHeight.nextInt())
        // print("\(positionAX) \(positionBX) \(positionCX) \(positionDX)")
        // print("\(positionAY) \(positionBY) \(positionCY) \(positionDX)")
        if edgesOnly
        {
            let positionRule = Int(arc4random() % 4)

            if positionRule == 0
            {
                positionAX = 0
                positionBX = 0
                positionCX = 0
                positionDX = 0
            }
            else if positionRule == 1
            {
                positionAX = Float(imageWidth)
                positionBX = Float(imageWidth)
                positionCX = Float(imageWidth)
                positionDX = Float(imageWidth)
            }
            else if positionRule == 2
            {
                positionAY = 0
                positionBY = 0
                positionCY = 0
                positionDY = 0
            }
            else
            {
                positionAY = Float(imageHeight)
                positionBY = Float(imageHeight)
                positionCY = Float(imageHeight)
                positionDY = Float(imageHeight)
            }
        }

        let particle = Particle(A: Vector4(x: positionAX + 400 + rand(), y: positionAY, z: -rand2(), w: rand()),
            B: Vector4(x: positionBX + 400 + rand(), y: positionBY, z: rand2(), w: rand()),
            C: Vector4(x: positionCX + 400 + rand(), y: positionCY, z: -rand2(), w: rand()),
            D: Vector4(x: positionDX + 400 + rand(), y: positionDY, z: rand2(), w: rand()))

        particlesParticleBufferPtr[index] = particle
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your goal here? To make the "milk" look more like water? Could you show us a mockup image of what you'd like it to look like? Because this: `Please find video on link below, this is look like Milk, but i am trying to make it as real Water Flow.` as a question is not enough for us to answer, and that's why you don't have any answers.

Comment: if you see video, this is milk spit from bottom to top, but what i want is to convert this milk spit to water particles spit.

Comment: Try taking away the loose particles around the edge of the formation, changing the background color to a rocky gray (the color of dark rocks), and changing the particles' color to a semi-transparent light blue/green. That should do it. Also, you might want to try widening the flow further towards the top.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because MVCE is an expired expirebox link.